# Internal resistor in a diode

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electrical-resistance, electronics

When we talk about the resistance of a diode (of the P and N region), is this resistance like the one inside an Electro-Motive Force or it acts like a normal resistor (external electric field exist)?

I was reading a book called Fundamentals of Microelectronics by Behzad Razavi and in its introduction of semiconductor, P and N Semiconductors acts like a normal resistor (External electric field is applied to make a drift current inside it)(See pics) but when studying about the diode, it mentions that a drift current is present in the diode because of the electric field of depletion region.[image: drift current in a semiconductor]

And Talking about a diode, if the P and N region acts like a resistor, so when there is a positive EMF applied to a diode, external electric field appears in the P and N region like a resistor and then P and N region has a drift current but also there is a diffusion current due to difference of concentration of holes and electrons, so is this external electric field acting on the diffusion current in the P and N region?

All in all, Im confused about this resistance, can somebody explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

Any electrical component has some kind of "resistance" - that is, it takes effort to move a current through it (leaving aside for a moment superconductors). We talk about "resistance" as a way to quantify this effort; for a simple resistor, the resistance has a constant value (at a given temperature) which means that the relationship between voltage and current is linear - the familiar Ohm's Law:

$$V = I\cdot R$$

It gets much more complicated with nonlinear devices such as those that contain semiconductor junctions. There is still a relationship between voltage and current, and we can therefore still talk about "resistance" but it no longer follows the simple Ohm's Law. There are various mechanisms in play that resist the flow of current - as you quote in your question. Now the current that you get depends on the concentration of charge carriers: in reverse bias, there are not very many in the "depletion" region - it is *depleted* of carriers. In that situation you can treat the junction as a resistor - low carrier concentration means that you need a lot of electric field to get a little bit of current flowing. In forward bias, charge carriers are injected into the junction and conduction is good.

Comment: Sorry still I didn't understand. Is there any electric field in the P and N region ? Im not talking about linearity like ohm's law just Im asking if there's electric field inside the P and N region? If yes, it should be acting on all charges right?(diffusion + drift)

Comment: Yes there is an electric field everywhere - otherwise a current could not be sustained.

Comment: Okay, and in the P and N region when there's resistance, the current is a drift current right?