# Resistance of depletion region

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, semiconductor-physics, electrical-resistance

The ideal diode equation is : I=Io[exp(qv/kT)-1]. My question is when we want to represent this ideal diode, it will be represented by a resistance of depletion region right? but is this resistance like a normal resistor? or this resistance is due to electric field that oppose diffusion current?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165251/2451

Comment: You might also like the hand-waving (my) answer here, http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/53302/1194

Comment: Diffusion current is the field independent part of carrier motion.  Drift current is field dependent.

Comment: Just I want to know the resistance of the depletion acts like a resistor and dissipate energy as heat or it is due to built in electric field of the junction.